# Consuming messages from RabbitMQ using lapin and accessing the AMQP message payload

Tags: rust, rabbitmq

I am looking for sample code illustrating consuming messages from RabbitMQ using lapin including accessing the AMQP message payload.

I am trying to run the "consumer.rs" example from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CleverCloud/lapin/master/examples/consumer.rs" but I am getting the below

```
.ack(BasicAckOptions::default())
 ^^^ method not found in `(lapin::Channel, Delivery)
```

Below is the code obtained from "https://github.com/CleverCloud/lapin/blob/master/examples/consumer.rs"

```
use futures_lite::StreamExt;
use lapin::{options::*, types::FieldTable, Connection, ConnectionProperties};
use tracing::info;

fn main() {
    if std::env::var("RUST_LOG").is_err() {
        std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "info");
    }

    tracing_subscriber::fmt::init();

    let addr = std::env::var("AMQP_ADDR").unwrap_or_else(|_| "amqp://127.0.0.1:5672/%2f".into());

    async_global_executor::block_on(async {
        let conn = Connection::connect(&addr, ConnectionProperties::default())
            .await
            .expect("connection error");

        info!("CONNECTED");

        //receive channel
        let channel = conn.create_channel().await.expect("create_channel");
        info!(state=?conn.status().state());

        let queue = channel
            .queue_declare(
                "hello",
                QueueDeclareOptions::default(),
                FieldTable::default(),
            )
            .await
            .expect("queue_declare");
        info!(state=?conn.status().state());
        info!(?queue, "Declared queue");

        info!("will consume");
        let mut consumer = channel
            .basic_consume(
                "hello",
                "my_consumer",
                BasicConsumeOptions::default(),
                FieldTable::default(),
            )
            .await
            .expect("basic_consume");
        info!(state=?conn.status().state());

        while let Some(delivery) = consumer.next().await {
            info!(message=?delivery, "received message");
            if let Ok(delivery) = delivery {
                delivery
                    .ack(BasicAckOptions::default())
                    .await
                    .expect("basic_ack");
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Please include the entire minimal code, especially if you have modified the example.

Comment: While the downvote wasn't from me, I have to apologize for my assumption that you modified the example and broke it. However, it is still good to post the code in the question, as hyperlinks can die, especially if you are linking to `master`, which is a moving target, rather than a specific Git commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are likely depending on the latest stable version of `lapin` in crates.io, which at this moment is 1.8. However, the example you are running is from the `master` branch. Seems like the developer is preparing for a new major version, 2.0, and as such, API of the library is different in `master`.

If you use the [same example file from the 1.8 branch](https://github.com/CleverCloud/lapin/blob/lapin-1.8.0/examples/consumer.rs), the code compiles.

Alternatively: use the example from `master` and the crate from `master`, rather than the latest stable release.

Answer (score 0):

Well below is my test code which excludes the main() function.
There is significant amount of extra code including logging configuration and so on. I did clean up this code with the hope that it may be of use to someone else.

There is still an issue, all the messages in the queue seem to get assigned to only one consumer and all these messages are moved from the "Ready" state to "Unacked" state almost instantly even though the only one message is processed per 10 seconds (due to the deliberate inclusion of sleep 10 sec).

I will be posting a new question on this issue.

The issue has been solved by correctly seeing Qos I have edited this function to include the call to basic_qos function.

```
use lapin::{options::*, Connection, ConnectionProperties, Result};
use futures_util::stream::StreamExt;
//use std::future::Future;
use tracing::info;
use slog::Drain;

pub fn lapin_test_consumer()->std::result::Result<i64, Box<std::io::Error>> {
    //env_logger::init();
    let log_file_name:&str="/tmp/lapin_test_consumer.log";
    let log_file_path=std::path::Path::new(&log_file_name);
    let dir_file_path=log_file_path.parent().unwrap();
    std::fs::create_dir_all(dir_file_path).unwrap();
    
    let log_file_handler_option = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open(log_file_name)
        //.unwrap()
    ;
    let log_file_handler=match log_file_handler_option
    {
        Ok(f)=>f
        ,Err(err)=>{
            println!("{:?}", err);
            panic!("Unable to open the log file '{}', '{:?}'",log_file_name,err);
        }
    };
    
    let my_log_drain = slog_async::Async::new(
        slog::Duplicate::new(
            slog::Filter::new(
                slog_term::FullFormat::new(
                    slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(log_file_handler,)
                )
                .use_file_location()
                .build()
                ,
                |record: &slog::Record|
                {
                    record.level().is_at_least(slog::Level::Debug)
                }    
            )
            //,slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(std::io::stdout())).build()
            ,slog::Duplicate::new(
                slog::Filter::new(
                    slog_term::FullFormat::new(
                        slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(std::io::stderr(),)
                    )
                    .use_file_location()
                    .build()
                    ,
                    //|record: &slog::Record| record.level().is_at_least(slog::Level::Warning)
                    |record: &slog::Record|
                    {
                        record.level().is_at_least(slog::Level::Debug)
                    }    
                    
                )
                //,slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(std::io::stdout())).build()
                ,slog_term::FullFormat::new(slog_term::TermDecorator::new().build()).use_file_location().build()
            )
        ).fuse()
    )
    .build()
    .fuse()
    ;
    let my_slog_logger=slog::Logger::root(my_log_drain, slog::o!("n" => env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME"),"v" => env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")));
    
    if std::env::var("RUST_LOG").is_err() {
        std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "info");
    }


    let addr:String = std::env::var("AMQP_ADDR").unwrap_or_else(
        |_|{
            format!("amqp://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?heartbeat=0"
                ,"abcd"//aMQPJobUser
                ,"abcd"//aMQPJobPasswd
                ,"somewhere.com"//aMQPJobHost
                ,5672//aMQPJobPort
                ,"lapin_test.test"//aMQPJobVirtualHost
            ).into()
        }
    );
    let amqp_conn_url:&str=&addr.as_str();
    

    //see "https://docs.rs/lapin/1.8.0/lapin/struct.Consumer.html"
    let res: std::result::Result<i64, Box<std::io::Error>> = async_global_executor::block_on(async {
            let sleep_duration_ms:u64=10000u64;
            let conn_result:std::result::Result<lapin::Connection, lapin::Error> = Connection::connect(
                &amqp_conn_url,
                ConnectionProperties::default().with_default_executor(2),//set the number of threads
                //ConnectionProperties::default().with_default_executor(8),
            )
            .await;
            let conn:lapin::Connection=match conn_result{
                Err(err)=>{
                    let bt=backtrace::Backtrace::new();
                    let log_message=format!(">>>>>At lapin_test_publisher(), pos 1b, some error has been encountered while trying to establish AMQP connection '{:?}', error is:'{:?}', backtrace is '{:?}'",&amqp_conn_url,&err,&bt);
                    slog::error!(my_slog_logger,"{}",log_message);
                    let custom_error=std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, &log_message.to_string()[..]);
                    return std::result::Result::Err(Box::new(custom_error));
                }
                Ok(conn2)=>{info!("CONNECTED");conn2}
            };
            


            //set basic_qos so each consumer may only have at most one message at at time
            channel_a.basic_qos(
                1
                ,BasicQosOptions{global:true}
            );
            
            let mut message_cnt:i64=0i64;let _some_i64:i64=message_cnt;
            let channel_a_result:Result<lapin::Channel>=conn.create_channel().await;
            let channel_a:lapin::Channel=match channel_a_result{
                Err(err)=>{
                    let bt=backtrace::Backtrace::new();
                    let log_message=format!(">>>>>At lapin_test_consumer(), pos 1b, some error has been encountered while trying to obtain a channel from AMQP connection '{:?}', error is:'{:?}', backtrace is '{:?}'",&amqp_conn_url,&err,&bt);
                    slog::error!(my_slog_logger,"{}",log_message);
                    let custom_error=std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, &log_message.to_string()[..]);
                    return std::result::Result::Err(Box::new(custom_error));
                    //return Err(err);
                }
                Ok(channel)=>{channel}
            };
            

            channel_a
                .exchange_declare(
                    "my_direct_exchange"
                    ,lapin::ExchangeKind::Direct
                    ,lapin::options::ExchangeDeclareOptions{
                        passive:false
                        ,durable:true
                        ,auto_delete:false
                        ,internal:false
                        ,nowait:false
                    }
                    ,lapin::types::FieldTable::default()//see "https://docs.rs/amq-protocol-types/6.1.0/amq_protocol_types/struct.FieldTable.html"
                )
            ;
            
            let queue = channel_a
                .queue_declare(
                    "hello.persistent"//:&str queue name
                    ,lapin::options::QueueDeclareOptions{
                        passive:false,
                        durable:true,
                        exclusive:false,
                        auto_delete:false,
                        nowait:false,
                    }
                    ,lapin::types::FieldTable::default()//see "https://docs.rs/amq-protocol-types/6.1.0/amq_protocol_types/struct.FieldTable.html"
                )
                .await
                .expect("queue_declare")
            ;
            channel_a
                .queue_bind(
                    "hello.persistent"
                    ,"my_direct_exchange"
                    ,"hello.persistent"
                    , lapin::options::QueueBindOptions{
                        nowait:false
                    }
                    ,lapin::types::FieldTable::default()//see "https://docs.rs/amq-protocol-types/6.1.0/amq_protocol_types/struct.FieldTable.html"
                )
            ;
            
            let consumer_a_result:Result<lapin::Consumer>=channel_a
                .basic_consume(
                    "hello.persistent",
                    "my_consumer",
                    lapin::options::BasicConsumeOptions{
                        no_local: true,//see "https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.no-local"
                        no_ack: false,//see "https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.no-ack" "If this field is set the server does not expect acknowledgements for messages. That is, when a message is delivered to the client the server assumes the delivery will succeed and immediately dequeues it. This functionality may increase performance but at the cost of reliability. Messages can get lost if a client dies before they are delivered to the application."
                        exclusive: false,
                        nowait: false,//see "https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.no-wait" "If set, the server will not respond to the method. The client should not wait for a reply method. If the server could not complete the method it will raise a channel or connection exception."
                    },
                    lapin::types::FieldTable::default(),
                )
                .await;
            let mut consumer_a:lapin::Consumer=match consumer_a_result{
                Err(err)=>{
                    let bt=backtrace::Backtrace::new();
                    let log_message=format!(">>>>>At lapin_test_consumer(), pos 1b, some error has been encountered while trying to obtain a consumer from AMQP connection '{:?}', error is:'{:?}', backtrace is '{:?}'",&amqp_conn_url,&err,&bt);
                    slog::error!(my_slog_logger,"{}",log_message);
                    let custom_error=std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, &log_message.to_string()[..]);
                    return std::result::Result::Err(Box::new(custom_error));
                    //return Err(err);
                }
                Ok(consumer)=>{consumer}
            };
        
            while let Some(delivery) = consumer_a.next().await {
                let (channel2, delivery2) = delivery.expect("error in consumer");
                message_cnt+=1;
                slog::info!(my_slog_logger,"------------------------------------------------------------------, message_cnt is:{}",&message_cnt);
                let s:String = match String::from_utf8(delivery2.data.to_owned()) {//delivery.data is of type Vec<u8>
                    Ok(v) => v,
                    Err(e) => panic!("Invalid UTF-8 sequence: {}", e),
                };          
                let log_message:String=format!("message_cnt is:{}, delivery_tag is:{}, exchange is:{}, routing_key is:{}, redelivered is:{}, properties is:'{:?}', received data is:'{:?}'"
                    ,&message_cnt
                    ,&delivery2.delivery_tag
                    ,&delivery2.exchange
                    ,&delivery2.routing_key
                    ,&delivery2.redelivered
                    ,&delivery2.properties
                    ,&s
                );
                slog::info!(my_slog_logger,"{}",log_message);
                std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(sleep_duration_ms));
                slog::info!(my_slog_logger,"After {}ms sleep.",sleep_duration_ms);
                channel2
                    .basic_ack(delivery2.delivery_tag, BasicAckOptions::default())
                    .await
                    .expect("ack")
                ;
            }
            Ok(message_cnt)
        }
    );
    res
}
```